# piping main method to tee will make trap method not see global variables

Tags: bash

I have a trap method which neither access global variables nor receive variables using `$*`. It looks like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

declare -a arr

finish_exit() {
        echo "* = $*"
        echo "arr = ${arr[*]}"
}
trap 'finish_exit "${arr[@]}"' EXIT

main() {
  arr+=("hello")
  arr+=("world")
}

main | tee -a /dev/null
```

The script prints ''.

If I remove the `| tee -a ...` snippet, the script prints 'hello\nworld' twice as expected.

Now, how can I pipe the output to a logfile WITHOUT loosing all context?
One solution would be to route everything from the script call, like so:
`./myscript.sh >> /dev/null`, but I think there should be a way to do this inside the script so I can log *EVERY* call, not just those run by cron.

Another solution I investigated was:

```sh
main() {
  ...
} >> /dev/null
```

But this will result in no output on the interactive shell.

---

Bonus karma for explanations why this subshell will "erase" global variables before the trap function is being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will make trap method not see global variables

The subshell does "sees" global variables, it does not execute the trap.

> why this subshell will "erase" global variables

From https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html :

> Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment that is a duplicate of the shell environment, **except that traps caught by the shell are reset** to the values that the shell inherited from its parent at invocation.

> how can I pipe the output to a logfile WITHOUT loosing all context?

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1> >(tee -a logfile)
trap 'echo world' EXIT
echo hello
```

or

```
{
   trap 'echo world' EXIT
   echo hello
} | tee -a logfile
```

And research: https://serverfault.com/questions/103501/how-can-i-fully-log-all-bash-scripts-actions and similar.

---

The following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
{
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

declare -a arr

finish_exit() {
        echo "* = $*"
        echo "arr = ${arr[*]}"
}
trap 'finish_exit "${arr[@]}"' EXIT

main() {
  arr+=("hello")
  arr+=("world")
}

main 

} | tee -a /dev/null
```

outputs for me:

```
* = hello
world
arr = hello
world
```

I added that `set -o pipefail` *before* the pipe, to preserve the exit status.

Comment: Ohhh, sneaky! :) So >(...) is redirecting to an executing process. It is similar to a pipe, but not the same, obviously. Thanks!

Comment: Explanation of 1: https://askubuntu.com/a/525787

Comment: echo from the trap method will not work the 2nd way: `: line 55: echo: write error: There is no process to read data written to a pipe.`
With the first method, there is no trap execution visible in `bash -x`

Comment: `line 55:` the script has 3 lines. Works fine for me. Still, the first solution is nicer.

Comment: ah. I only wrapped the call to main  and trap into braces. Hmm... it is a bit ugly, imho. But thanks, I see now why it was not working for me.